# how to resolve spyder crash in ubuntu

Tags: python, crash, spyder

I have using  Spyder 3.3.6  and python Python 3.7.3 64-bit | Qt 5.9.6 | PyQt5 5.9.2 | Linux 5.0.0-37-generic  with anaconda in ubunut 18.04 machine for a while with no problem , to day a have started spyder and it keep crash and i get this , so what can i do to start spyder again without reinstall all

```
    $ spyder
1584271806 WARNING torsocks[18523]: [syscall] Unsupported syscall number 217. Denying the call (in tsocks_syscall() at syscall.c:568)
    1584271809 WARNING torsocks[18515]: [syscall] Unsupported syscall number 118. Denying the call (in tsocks_syscall() at syscall.c:568)
    [18515:18515:0315/123009.991958:FATAL:credentials.cc(47)] Check failed: sys_getresuid(&ruid, &euid, &suid) == 0. : Function not implemented
    #0 0x7faae9a7a0be <unknown>
    #1 0x7faae9a8c6c2 <unknown>
    #2 0x7faae9a8da3c <unknown>
    #3 0x7faaea4513cf <unknown>
    #4 0x7faaea451bbb <unknown>
    #5 0x7faae97f61a5 <unknown>
    #6 0x7faae95a0994 <unknown>
    #7 0x7faae95a4727 <unknown>
    #8 0x7faae9436542 <unknown>
    #9 0x7faae9436718 <unknown>
    #10 0x7faae942d681 <unknown>
    #11 0x7faae942d732 QtWebEngineCore::WebContentsAdapter::WebContentsAdapter()
    #12 0x7faaedcda376 <unknown>
    #13 0x7faaedcd80c4 <unknown>
    #14 0x7faaedcd8252 QWebEnginePage::QWebEnginePage()
    #15 0x7faaedd09689 sipQWebEnginePage::sipQWebEnginePage()
    #16 0x7faaedd09812 init_type_QWebEnginePage
    #17 0x7faaeff5d494 <unknown>
    #18 0x55f6d6f689b8 _PyObject_FastCallKeywords
    #19 0x55f6d6fc4026 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
    #20 0x55f6d6f0650b _PyFunction_FastCallDict
    #21 0x55f6d6f1dc43 _PyObject_Call_Prepend
    #22 0x55f6d6f600aa slot_tp_init
    #23 0x55f6d6f689b8 _PyObject_FastCallKeywords
    #24 0x55f6d6fc4026 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
    #25 0x55f6d6f0650b _PyFunction_FastCallDict
    #26 0x55f6d6f1dc43 _PyObject_Call_Prepend
    #27 0x55f6d6f600aa slot_tp_init
    #28 0x55f6d6f689b8 _PyObject_FastCallKeywords
    #29 0x55f6d6fc4026 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
    #30 0x55f6d6f0650b _PyFunction_FastCallDict
    #31 0x55f6d6f1dc43 _PyObject_Call_Prepend
    #32 0x55f6d6f600aa slot_tp_init
    #33 0x55f6d6f689b8 _PyObject_FastCallKeywords
    #34 0x55f6d6fc4026 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
    #35 0x55f6d6f054f9 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName
    #36 0x55f6d6f065d5 _PyFunction_FastCallDict
    #37 0x55f6d6f1dc43 _PyObject_Call_Prepend
    #38 0x55f6d6f600aa slot_tp_init
    #39 0x55f6d6f689b8 _PyObject_FastCallKeywords
    #40 0x55f6d6fc4026 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
    #41 0x55f6d6f05db9 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName
    #42 0x55f6d6f67a27 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords
    #43 0x55f6d6fc3ed9 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
    #44 0x55f6d6f6779b _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords
    #45 0x55f6d6fbf846 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
    #46 0x55f6d6f6779b _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords
    #47 0x55f6d6fc3ed9 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
    #48 0x55f6d6f6779b _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords
    #49 0x55f6d6fbf846 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
    #50 0x55f6d6f054f9 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName
    #51 0x55f6d6f063c4 PyEval_EvalCodeEx
    #52 0x55f6d6f063ec PyEval_EvalCode
    #53 0x55f6d701e874 run_mod
    #54 0x55f6d7028b81 PyRun_FileExFlags
    #55 0x55f6d7028d73 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags
    #56 0x55f6d7029e5f pymain_main
    #57 0x55f6d7029f7c _Py_UnixMain
    #58 0x7fab0508eb6b __libc_start_main
    #59 0x55f6d6fcf122 <unknown>

    Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by  **torsocks** and the solution was to stop it with this command
**source torsocks off**

***i hope somme one can give me more explication in how torsocks have lead to the crash of spyder***

Comment: If you still have a question about this problem, either update your question or start a new one. Questions shouldn't be asked as part of an answer.